# How to give a Flatpak app access to a directory

Tags: permissions, flatpak

I installed Elisa music player from Flathub, but it refuses to see my Music partition, so I can't add any music to it's library unless I copy it to `/home/my_user/`.

**Is there a way to give a Flatpak application permission to access non canonical addresses?**

Aside from specifying it when compiling it...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do this via the command line. The specific command you need is (it may need to be run with `sudo`):

```
flatpak override <package_name_here> --filesystem=<path_here>
```

If you have an odd path & it complains about an "unexpected filesystem suffix", just put the path part in quotes.

If you wish to remove access to a particular address, use "`--nofilesystem`":

```
flatpak override <package_name_here> --nofilesystem=<path_here>
```

A more complete list of permissions/commands is found [here](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html).

Comment: Thanks, I can add Dropbox folder to the WPS Office path

Comment: I did this with `--filesystem=/home/myuser` and it worked. I then tried with `/` to beeing able to access my shares at `/mnt` and from now on, when I try to start the app I get `wrap: Can't create file at /run/user/1000/bus: No such device or address`. My app is `Flacon` (I need it for splitting a large `flac` file`).

Comment: Found a solution - `flatpak override <package_name_here> --nofilesystem=<path_here>`. So for you, do `flatpak override com.github.Flacon --nofilesystem=/`.

Comment: Note that, according to [the official docs](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html), these directories are blacklisted: `/lib`, `/lib32`, `/lib64`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr`, `/boot`, `/root`, `/tmp`, `/etc`, `/app`, `/run`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, `/var`, meaning you can't give an app access to them even using the override method.

Comment: What's missing from this answer is a way to check the current filesystem permissions. I couldn't find it in the linked documentation.

Comment: `$ flatpak list` to get the package name.

Answer (score 71):

To add to the other answer, another solution that worked for me was installing [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal). It makes setting permissions super easy and also has the added benefit of making the existing permissions really clear. Here's what adding a directory to steam looks like in Flatseal:

[image: Adding extra directory to steam in Flatseal]

I added the directory "MediaSSD" there, everything else is default.

Comment: Changing permissions might also reset all the preferences, at least this is what happened with Thunderbird. All the account settings were done, but, at least, now I can drag/drop files to attach them to messages!

Comment: Because this tool downloads more than 200 megabytes of data in my case, it is possibly better to use other methods that does not require any further data installed.

Answer (score 10):

Run once to allow access to normal files on the host, not including host OS or system internals:

```
sudo flatpak override ApplicationIDHere --filesystem=host
```

ApplicationID is shown using command: `sudo flatpak list`

Then:

```
flatpak run ApplicationIDHere
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me for PPSSPP flatpak not being able to access $USER/.var/app/org.ppsspp.PPSSPP (which was a symlinked folder, but both the base folder and symlinked folder had correct permissions).

Answer (score 0):

To add to this answer, which is similar to what Hassan said. I tried installing WhatsApp Web as a PWA. I needed to add these lines into Flatseal in order for Chrome being able to create a shortcut with a matching icon:

`~/.local/share/applications`

`~/.local/share/icons`

**Remember to restart Chrome for the changes to take effect**

[Flatseal Chrome - File system - Other files - Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Cby.png)